# SQL Server stored procedure - SELECT statement then use results in INSERT statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure that will get results from one table then copy them to another. It isn't an exact match, I'm changing 1 column and ignoring another. There are 5 columns and on average 3-5 results if that is relevant.

I basically need to:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE somecolumn = 1
```

Then for every result

```
INSERT INTO anothertable (a,b,c) VALUES (@a, @b, @c)
```

What is the best way to do this within a stored procedure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in one statement:

```
INSERT AnotherTable (a, b, c)
SELECT a, b, c
FROM SomeTable
WHERE SomeColumn = 1
```

Wherever possible, avoid doing things in loops/cursors/RBAR (Row By Agonizing Row) and instead try to think in SET-based approaches like above.

Comment: Could 'a' be replaced with @z, a predefined variable outside of the table?

Comment: @MattP - yes, that would result in each row inserted having that same value

Answer (score 3):

I would try something like

```
insert into anothertable (a,b,c)
select a, b, c from sometable where somecolumn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can insert directly from a select query:

```
INSERT INTO anothertable (a,b,c)
SELECT @a, @b, @c FROM sometable WHERE somecolumn = 1
```

Comment: Will this work when @a is a separate variable defined before the statement and only b and c are in the table?

Comment: Yes - you can mix and match if needed - you could declare @a as a variable, and then replace @b and @c with column names from sometable and then you'd be inserting all the values of columns, with the same value of @a for each.